# Space with diagonal matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Good evening everyone, I am trying to calculate the following quotient vector space $\mathbb{M_3(R)}/D$ Where $D$ is the space of diagonal matrices of order 3.

My work:

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices such that $A,B∈M_3(R)$, We say that $A∼B$ iff $A−B∈D$. But I do not know how to continue, that is, I do not know how to make this happen. I need to find the equivalence class of a matrix $A∈M_3(R)$. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $M_3(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^9$ and $D \cong \mathbb{R}^3$, so we will have $M_3(\mathbb{R})/D \cong \mathbb{R}^6$. In fact, we can see

$$ M_3(\mathbb{R})/D \cong \{A\in M_3(\mathbb{R}) \; | \; A_{ii} = 0\}$$

The equivalence class of $A$ is $\{A+\lambda I$ | $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}\}$, leaving us six entries to vary.

Comment: How can I see $M_3(\mathbb{R})/D \cong \{A\in M_3(\mathbb{R}) \; | \; A_{ii} = 0\}$? Sorry!

Comment: Construct a map $M_3(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \{A\in M_3(\mathbb{R}) \; | \; A_{ii} = 0\}$ sending $A \mapsto B$ where $B_{ij} = A_{ij}$ if $i \neq j$ and $B_{ij} = 0$ if $i = j$. This has kernel $D$ and is surjective, giving the required isomorphism by the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Be this other exercise very similar, what if I want to see this vector space quotient $\mathbb{M_3(R)}/S$?, where $S$ represents the set of scalar matrices of order 3. What would be the equivalence class of any matrix $A$ and what isomorphism would define?

Answer (score 1):

Two matrices are equivalent if their difference is diagoanl; in other words, if the off diagonal entries of two matrices are the same then they are equivalent.  In particular, all diagonal matrices are equivalent. The dimension of $M_3$ is $9$ and the dimension of the quotient space is $9-3$ since it is the off diagonal entries that define this quotient space. Is this object clear now?

EDIT:

Suppose $A$ is a matrix with entries $A_{ij}$ then $B\in [A]$ ( the equivalence class containing $A$) if $B_{ij}=A_{ij}$ for all $i,j$ whenever $i\neq j$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's still not quite clear to me, how can I find the equivalent class of any $A$ Matrix 3x3 in this quotient?

Comment: What do you mean whith "all diagonal matrices are equivalent"?

Comment: Wellcthe difference of two diagonal matrcies is diagonal so by this definition they must be equivalent.